# select item from listview and cast to my custom object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to select object from listview and cast to my custom object like this

```
MyObject foo = (MyObject)MyListView.SelectedItems[0];
```

but this give's me compile error

> Error 4   Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to
>   'MyObject'

Comment: How do you add data to list view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default `ListView` is not data-bindable (i.e. you can't assign some objects as data source of list view). It contains `ListViewItem` objects, which cannot be casted to your data type. That's why you getting this error.

If you want to get your custom object from `ListViewItem` then you need to construct it manually from `ListViewItem`:

```
ListViewItem item = (MyObject)MyListView.SelectedItems[0];
MyObject foo = new MyObject();
foo.FirstName = item.Text;
foo.LastName = item.SubItems[1].Text;
foo.Age = Int32.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text);
```

OR you can store custom object in `Tag` property of `ListViewItem` and get it back:

```
ListViewItem item = (MyObject)MyListView.SelectedItems[0];
MyObject foo = (MyObject)item.Tag;
```

BTW consider to use `DataGridView` which supports binding.

Comment: Another suggestion is to create your own `ListViewItem`-derived object that holds an instance of the item you wish to display in the ListView and provide a custom property, like `{ItemName}Instance` or something--assuming your item to be displayed doesn't take up a lot of memory and isn't hard to construct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create your object differently, not casting in this way.

If you retrieve the text in the item, then create your object using that text.

```
string txt   = MyListView.SelectedItems[0].Text;
MyObject foo = new MyObject(txt);
```

Then use your object in the usual way. It is difficult to tell any more about what you need without more details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ListItems are objects of your custom class `MyObject`
Now in the latest Xamarin, you can do it by getting `SelectedItem` and cast it to your object type.

```
public class ItemSelectionDemo
{
    public void ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyObject item = (MyObject)MyListView.SelectedItem;
        Debug.WriteLine("Selected item Id: " + item.id);
        Debug.Writeline("Selected item Name: " + item.name);
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
```

You can also use `SelectedItemChangedEventArgs` in the method and get the selected item and the cast it to your object class type.

```
public void ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyObject item = e.SelectedItem as MyObject;
    Debug.WriteLine("Selected item Id: " + item.id);
    Debug.Writeline("Selected item Name: " + item.name);
}
```