# extract a specific column from a Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a ListView and I will like to extract the date column from it.  I was able to find the keyId but I can't find out how to extract the date.  I add the class and the datasource

```
public partial class DocApointment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  .....

   protected void DocApointment_Update()
   {
    int keyId = 0;
    int indxChkBox = 0;

   foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
       CheckBox MyCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
       if (MyCheckBox.Checked) 

       {
            keyId = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Value);
            choiceddl = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

           var itemDateBooked = (ListView1.Items. .dateBooked)  <=== I am trying to find the
                                                                     syntax to extract the date
                                                                     from the selected listview
```

Here is the datasource

```
       <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="apointmentId" 
         DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" >
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
              <tr style="">
                <!-- <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="ApointmentIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                      Eval("ApointmentId") %>' />
                </td>   -->
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="doctorNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                      Eval("doctorName") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="dateBookedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateBooked", 
                       "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>' />
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="MyCheckBox" runat="server"
                            value='<%# Eval("apointmentId") %>'
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />

                 </td>
             </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the debugger you'll see that the `ListViewDataItem` class has a property of type `object` named `DataItem`.

This object is of the class of the collection that was bount to de `ListView`.

So, to access its properties, you simply have to cast it to the original type:

```
  ((TheClassOfTheElements)(item.DataItem)).TheRequiredProperty
```

Yo can use the debugger, and inspect the data item to find this expression, and then copy+paste it in tour code.

Comment: I am trying this but I don't understand how it will extract my date from the listview  sorry I am new to C#.  Here what I tried  but it generate a null ref exception.      var dateItem = ((DateTime)(item.DataItem)).Date;

Comment: No, you have to convert the (item.DataItem) to the class of the collection elements that you're binding to your ListView, not to DateTime. Can you show me the class that you're binding to the ListView? How do you define the data source of the ListView?

Comment: I've not used Linq data sources, so I don't know what type to expect to recover form it. Set a breakpoint in the first line of your foreach (CheckBox... ). Debug your app, and when you get to this breakpoint, ad a watch for item. When you get there, tell me what is the item's class.

Comment: In fact, if you drill down in the wtach window, you should be able to find a way to get the required property

Comment: item -base(DataItem, DataItemIndex, DisplayItemIndex, DisplayIndex) -Non-Public members - item

Comment: Excuse me.. add a wath for item.DataItem, and let me know the type of DataItem (column type in the watch window). We neraly get it!

Comment: item.DataItem is an object nothing under it.  I am reading this post   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857367/select-item-from-listview-and-cast-to-my-custom-object    and it is said  Default ListView is not data-bindable (i.e. you can't assign some objects as data source of list view). It contains ListViewItem objects, which cannot be casted to your data type. That's why you getting this error.

If you want to get your custom object from ListViewItem then you need to construct it manually from ListViewItem:   If I want to do so I need to have the index of the selected listview.

Comment: item.DataItem cannot be a plain object. The type of the variable is object, but not the type of the underlying object. Please look carefully in the watch window. If you are not able to find the type there, add a watch for `item.DataItem.GetType()` and show me the result. Take into account that in the other post they're working on item itself, not on item.DataItem.

Comment: item.DataItem from the Watch windows, I cannot go under it. value is null and type object.   I tried to put var item2 = item.DataItem.GetType(); in the code and it gave me an error null object.