# Can't get ListViewItem when using custom object

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

I've searched and searched and searched but can't find an answer.

C# and WPF, I have a single ListView with 5 columns and each column has a TextBox in it.

My custom class

```
public class SomeThing
{
    public String field1 { get; set; }
    public String field2 { get; set; }
    public String field3 { get; set; }
    public String field4 { get; set; }
    public String field5 { get; set; }
}
```

My add code

```
SomeThing item = new SomeThing();
lstItems.Items.Add(item);
```

My keydown code

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            Grid grid = (Grid)tb.Parent;                

            if (tb.Tag.Equals("Price"))
            {
                if(lstItems.Items.Count <= lstItems.SelectedIndex + 1) {                     
                    SomeThing item = new SomeThing();
                    lstItems.Items.Add(item);                        
                }

                lstItems.SelectedIndex = lstItems.SelectedIndex + 1;                   

                ListViewItem selectedItem = (ListViewItem)lstItems.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.lstItems.SelectedItem);

                    e.Handled = true;
            }                               

        }
    }
```

But

```
ListViewItem selectedItem = (ListViewItem)lstItems.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.lstItems.SelectedItem);
```

Is always null,

```
this.lstItems.SelectedItem
```

is just an object of instance "SomeThing".

How do I get the ListView Container?

How do I focus the TextBox on the new selected row?

Please help

Comment: Did you try casting it to your custom class?  `(Something)this.lstItems.SelectedItem`

Comment: @jpaugh78 This is when I inspect whilst debugging. I can't cast it to a ListViewItem because it's of type SomeThing

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize a ListView worked a little different than the controls I usually use.  I found a thread that could be helpful to you though:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857367/select-item-from-listview-and-cast-to-my-custom-object

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you are trying to get something from the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) that has not been generated yet at the time you ask for it. Adding an item to an `ItemsControl` (which `ListView` is a subclass of) does not immediately create a container for that item. There is a delay involved.

This is not really the ideal way to be working with `ItemsControl` instances. They are really designed around being used with the MVVM design pattern. However, if you need to work with it this way for some reason, then you will need to pay attention to the [`Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.status(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) and the associated [`StatusChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.statuschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

So, something along these lines:

```
    if (myItemsControlInstance.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        // You should be able to get the container using ContainerFromItem
    }
    else
    {
        // You will have to wait
        myItemsControlInstance.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += myItemsControlInstance_StatusChanged;
    }

...

void myItemsControlInstance_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myItemsControlInstance.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        myItemsControlInstance.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= myEventHandler;
        // You should be able to get the container now using ContainerFromItem.
        // However, layout hasn't been performed on it yet at this point, so there is
        // no guarantee that the item is in good condition to be messed with yet.
        LayoutUpdated += app_LayoutUpdated;
    }
}

void app_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LayoutUpdated -= app_LayoutUpdated;
    if (myItemsControlInstance.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        // Now, you can finally get the container using ContainerFromItem and do something with it.
    }
    else
    {
        // It looks like more items needed to be generated...
        myItemsControlInstance.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += myItemsControlInstance_StatusChanged;
    }
}
```

There are a few more things you have to watch out for though when working with `ItemContainerGenerator` directly like this:

- The `Status` on the generator can be [`Error`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.generatorstatus(v=vs.110).aspx). You might want to check for that, though I have never seen it happen.
- If the `ItemsControl` is using a virtualizing panel to contain the items, it is possible that you are trying to access an item that is not in view and therefore doesn't exist. You can either override the type of panel used to not virtualize, such as `StackPanel` instead of `VirtualizingStackPanel` by setting the [`ItemsPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx) property, or you can make sure the item is scrolled into view somehow before starting the process (which is a whole separate topic).

My recommendation would be to switch to an MVVM model and read up on how to work with `ItemsControl` in a more natural way, because doing it this way is complicated and error-prone.